# Error while converting dicom tags in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsx, dicom

I am trying to convert and list dicom tags from .dcm files into excel (using python) but certain tags are showing errors (PatientName, PixelSpacing etc) while conversion.

Some of the tags are showing 'None' in excel file although they contain/show data (SliceThickness,  SpacingBetweenSlices etc) in Dicom format. How can I resolve this?

Besides, I want the output file to be in a different folder without using os.chdir() command. I tried several method but could not figure it out.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import xlsxwriter 
import sys 
import dicom 
import os.path

root = input("Enter Directory Name: ") path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory") i=1

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:

        os.rename(os.path.join(path, name), os.path.join(path,'MR000'+ str(i)+'.dcm'))
        i=i+1
        print (os.path.join(path, name))

         dcm_files = [] for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for names in files:
        if names.endswith(".dcm"):
            dcm_files.append(os.path.join(root, names))

for dcm_file in dcm_files:
    ds = dicom.read_file(dcm_file)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.path.basename(dcm_file) + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    a = os.getcwd ()
    print (a)


    data = (
            #["PatientName", ds.get("PatientName", "None")],
            ["PatientID", ds.get("PatientID", "None")],
            ["PatientBirthDate", ds.get("PatientBirthDate", "None")],
            ["PatientSex", ds.get("PatientSex", "None")],
            ["RepetitionTime", ds.get("RepetitionTime", "None")],
            ["EchoTime", ds.get("EchoTime", "None")],
            ["Modality", ds.get("Modality", "None")],
            ["Manufacturer", ds.get("Manufacturer", "None")],
            ["InstitutionName", ds.get("Institution Name", "None")],
            #["ReferringPhysicianName", ds.get("ReferringPhysicianName", "None")],
            ["StudyDescription", ds.get("StudyDescription", "None")],
            ["PatientAge", ds.get("PatientAge", "None")],
            ["SliceThickness", ds.get("SliceThickness(mm)", "None")],
            ["SpacingBetweenSlices", ds.get("SpacingBetweenSlices", "None")],
            ["SeriesNumber", ds.get("SeriesNumber", "None")],
            #["PixelSpacing", ds.get("PixelSpacing", "None")],
            ["RequestedProcedureID", ds.get("RequestedProcedureID", "None")],
            ["Rows", ds.get("Rows", "None")],
            ["Columns", ds.get("Columns", "None")]
            )

    row = 0
    col = 0

    for name, value in (data):
        worksheet.write(row, col,     name)
        worksheet.write(row + 1, col, value)
        col += 1

    workbook.close()
```

Some data from the dicom tag:

```
Columns: 256
InstitutionName: UIC MR2
PatientAge: 046Y
PatientBirthDate: 19630503
PatientID: 080524186
PatientName: PEREZ^GUILLERMINA
PatientPosition: HFS
PatientSex: F
PixelSpacing: ['0.9375', '0.9375']
Rows: 256
SliceThickness: 5
SpacingBetweenSlices: 10
StudyID: 586323788
StudyTime: 204546
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes I can see in the code... for example "SliceThickness(mm)" is not a correct dicom keyword, and "Institution Name" has a space.  I think it is better not to repeat the keyword.  The code below sets the keyword list outside the loop and uses the same name to look up the value. And it checks for certain types that can't be written (lists and PersonName3) and converts them.  The list is simply turned into a string with a comma between the elements; you could try to write in different cells or some other solution.

```
import xlsxwriter 
import sys 
import dicom 
import os.path
from dicom.valuerep import PersonName3

keywords = ("PatientName",
            "PatientID",
            "PatientBirthDate",
            "PatientSex",
            "RepetitionTime",
            "EchoTime",
            "Modality",
            "Manufacturer",
            "InstitutionName",
            "ReferringPhysicianName",
            "StudyDescription",
            "PatientAge",
            "SliceThickness",
            "SpacingBetweenSlices",
            "SeriesNumber",
            "PixelSpacing",
            "RequestedProcedureID",
            "Rows",
            "Columns",
           )

# ...
# XXX fill in dcm_files list
dcm_files = [r"C:\temp\test.dcm"]   

for dcm_file in dcm_files:
    ds = dicom.read_file(dcm_file)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.path.basename(dcm_file) + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 0
    col = 0

    for keyword in keywords:
        value = ds.get(keyword, "None")
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = ", ".join([str(x) for x in value])
        elif isinstance(value, PersonName3):
            value = str(value)
        worksheet.write(row, col, keyword)
        worksheet.write(row + 1, col, value)
        col += 1

    workbook.close()
```

I've changed the dcm_files part just for a simpler test; you could put back the code for your full list.

I don't know why SpacingBetweenSlices didn't work in your code, but it is coming across fine from my test file.

As to outputting to different folder, you should be able to just use `os.path.join` with your desired location and the xlsx file name you created.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. One of the other problems that I am facing while compiling is that my original .dcm files are getting lost if I run the program more than once, every time after renaming the original files. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - but if you rename the files then the original name will no longer be there.  Perhaps you mean to copy instead?  In any case there is no need to rename - the pydicom reading leaves the original files unchanged.